# Why can't seaborn.pairplot finish drawing this plot?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, networkx

I have a dataframe `central`

[image]

Then I want to plot the pairwise relationships between the columns with `sns.pairplot(central)`. Could you please explain why the process just runs forever? I tried on both my laptop and Colab, but the problem persists.

```
import urllib3
%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # Change the image format to svg for better quality

import networkx as nx
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
from scipy import stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

## Import dataset
http = urllib3.PoolManager()
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/WebMining/main/airports.net'
f = http.request('GET', url)
open('airports.net', 'wb').write(f.data)
G = nx.read_pajek('airports.net', encoding = 'UTF-8')
G = nx.DiGraph(G)

## Compute measures of centrality
degree_central = nx.degree_centrality(G)
closeness_central = nx.closeness_centrality(G)
eigen_central = nx.eigenvector_centrality_numpy(G, max_iter = 200)
katz_central = nx.katz_centrality_numpy(G)
between_central = nx.betweenness_centrality(G)
pagerank = nx.pagerank_numpy(G)
[hub, authority] = nx.hits(G)

##  Create a dataframe using with above calculated centralities
central = pd.DataFrame([degree_central, closeness_central, eigen_central, katz_central, between_central, hub, authority]).T
central.columns = ['degree', 'closeness', 'eigen', 'katz', 'between', 'hub', 'authority']
central

## Plot the pairwise relationships between centralities
sns.pairplot(central)
```

Comment: The problem is caused by column `eigen_central` but I don't know what exactly the nature of this problem is. The column contains float64 values, as all other columns. It does not contain NaN or Inf values. It is the only column that contains negative values but this should not be the problem. The problem disappears when you add another column to it but not if you add a float value. Maybe some tricky numpy type problem?

Comment: More on this problem: It is not a specific value of this column, as I suspected at one point. You can plot `sns.pairplot(central.iloc[n:n+150, :])`  for any `n` but not `sns.pairplot(central.iloc[n:n+200, :])`.The histogram of `eigen_central` looks weird, though, and an isolated `histplot` for this column also does not work, so seemingly this is the main problem.  I followed this question and do hope, somebody else can shed light on this behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For reasons unknown to me, the histplot for column `eigen_central` has a problem determining a reasonable number of bins. The pairplot works with kde plots in the diagonal `sns.pairplot(central, diag_kind="kde")`, and the histplot for column `eigen_central` alone also does not work as expected. You can overcome this problem by defining the bin number:

```
sns.pairplot(central, diag_kws = {"bins": 10})
```

Output:
[image]

I will upvote any answer that can provide a reason why seaborn has problems defining the bins. This problem is seaborn-specific as `plt.hist(central.eigen)` works as expected but not `sns.histplot(central.eigen)`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort in clearing my confusion. I wonder if the very small values of column `eigen_central ` is the cause of problem. For example, the column contains `-3.574483e-18` and `1.179547e-17`.

Comment: Unlikely. It is probably something about the distribution of these data that throws off the bin calculation by seaborn. Hopefully, @mwaskom appears here and enlightens us.

Comment: This is an open issue, related to numpy proposing too many bins: https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2325

Comment: @JohanC This only happens with certain datasets. Is anything known about specific properties of failing datasets?

Comment: Probably when a lot of different magnitudes are involved.  For example `sns.histplot(10**np.random.uniform(-20, -4, 1000))` as `np.histogram_bin_edges(10**np.random.uniform(-20, -4, 1000), 'auto').size` gives sizes larger than 20000.