# Python Seaborn plotting blank histogram

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, seaborn

I'm trying to plot a histogram using seaborn in python. But all it gives me is a blank figure.

Here is the `describe()` of my column:

[image]

The code:

```py
plt.subplots(figsize=(7,7))
sns.histplot(data=contratos, x='duracao_contrato', bins='fd')
```

The output:

[image]

Comment: Did the bin estimation fail? Can happen in some estimator-data combinations. What happens if you define `bins=10`?

Comment: Yeah, I think it was the problem. It's a bit weird that I didn't receive any warning message. After removing the negative values and setting the bins number, it worked!

Comment: The negative numbers should not be the problem. Another bin estimator may work perfectly well with your dataset. Please [see here for the relevant bin keywords](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges) - seaborn passes this to numpy. And some datasets do not fulfill implicit prerequisites of some estimators. However, it is [indeed annoying](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978748/8881141) that they fail silently.

Comment: Before posting here I was trying with fd, but it took a time and then showed this blank histogram too. The other ones (sturges, scott, doane), create too large bins (due to the wide range of the data), and just give a big bar on the bin 0. I guess that the bin methods are probably defining too large bins. After setting it manually, it looked better. Thanks you so much @Mr.T!!! Please asnwer officialy so I can mark as resolved.

Comment: I can reproduce the problem where bins = 'fd' however bins = 'doane' appears to render the histogram. It would be useful if seaborn could throw a warning to tell us why bins = 'fd' does not render a chart successfully

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems the automatic bin estimation failed in your case. This can happen for some estimator-data combinations (see [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65977652/why-cant-seaborn-pairplot-finish-drawing-this-plot/65978748#65978748) here).

Generally, estimators like `fd` should work with seaborn - seaborn passes the [bin keyword](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.histogram_bin_edges.html#numpy.histogram_bin_edges) to numpy because the calculation of the histogram data is performed by numpy. Unfortunately, if estimators fail in their bin calculation, they fail silently, so it is often not clear why the graph is not plotted.

So, what can be done in this case? First, one can try to use `bins=auto` - a versatile estimator that chooses the "best" of the available estimator functions. If this is unsatisfactory, try other estimators like `bins="doane"` or `bins="stone"` (seemingly, you have done this already). If this is still unsatisfactory define the number `bins=10` (evenly spaced bins) or ranges `bins=[-5000, 300, 350, 370, 400, 8000]` (unevenly spaced bins).
BTW, another silent error can be created by using `inf` in the bin list `bins=[-np.inf, 300, 350, 370, 400, np.inf]` will probably also create an empty graph (I assume because the bins are used to determine the x-range of the graph).