# Unable to plot histogram using seaborn.hist for just 1 lakh rows and execution takes too much time

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, histogram

The seaborn version is `0.11.2`. The DataFrame has only `103056` entries in a column.
I want to plot the histogram for this values but `sns.hist()` is not showing graph and the code remains in execution process.

Please see the code and the DataFrame to get better clarity.

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# data
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Gkchandora/Temporary/main/MyData.csv")
print(f"No: of row in df : {len(df)}")
```

```
No of rows in df : 103056
```

DataFrame preview

```
        A
0   0.022241
1   1.514003
2   1.589536
3   0.000000
4   5.222472
```

Histogram Plotting code

```py
sns.histplot(data = df, x = "A")
```

I am easily able to plot using `df.hist` but not able to getting what is wrong with `sns.hisplot()` and its just a column with 100 000 entries.
Can anyone explain?

Comment: Maybe the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66374594/8881141)?

Comment: @Mr.T  shared question is not helpful in this case. The execution takes too much (>10min) and I have to stop the kernel.

Comment: Looks like a perfect fit to me because `bins=10` or `bins="doane"` generates a histogram. The seaborn histogram estimator often fails with data distributions like yours (one bin with 99% of data, the rest broadly scattered over a large range).

Comment: @Mr.T Thanks. Now I got the logic and its working

Comment: A bit more on the underlying problem can be found in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65978748/8881141).

Comment: `sns.histplot(data=df, x="A", bins=np.arange(-11000, 5000, 1000)).set_yscale('log')` you should probably clean the dataframe first, by removing outliers. Or `sns.histplot(data=df[df.A.between(0, 100)], x='A', bins=10).set_yscale('log')`